# Unwrapping a optional nil when getting value out of a firebase snapshot dictionary in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am having trouble unwrapping a optional nil when getting value out of a firebase snapshot dictionary in swift 4.0

Here's my code

```
Database.database().reference().child("questionPosts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                //var questionName = dict["name"] as! String
                //var created_by = dict["email"] as! String
                let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String
                let created_by = dict["email"] as? String

                let question = Question(questionName: questionTitle!, created_by: created_by!)

                self.questions.append(question)



                print(self.questions.count)

            }
        }
```

And when I run this it gives me an error saying:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

I am also writing this code in swift 4.0 in Xcode 9.0

could anyone please help I have been banging my head on this for weeks

so help would be really appreciated

Comment: Check if the **key**s for your dictionary return valid `String` **value**s.

Comment: let question = Question(questionName: questionTitle!, created_by: created_by!)

in this line you can remove ! sign.

Comment: @SagarBhut I tried have but it gives me a error and autocompletes it to have a question mark

Comment: you need to set Default value of 

 let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String
 let created_by = dict["email"] as? String

by replace

 let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
 let created_by = dict["email"] as? String ?? ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below code with your code.

```
let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
let created_by = dict["email"] as? String ?? ""
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need those 2 values to continue executing, I would suggest using `guard` then you'll be able keep them in a line and avoid indents for ease of readability.

```
defer { print(self.questions.count) }

guard let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else { return }
guard let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String else { return }
guard let created_by = dict["email"] as? String else { return }

let question = Question(questionName: questionTitle, created_by: created_by)
self.questions.append(question)
```